# Django not saving form data

Tags: python, django

I've made a simple test django project that's a simple list of posts. And I'm trying to add functionality to update a post. Everything seems to be working, except the edits aren't saved to the database.

I've checked the cleaned data to see if the updated data is coming through, and it is, but the save() function doesn't seem to actually do anything.

models.py

```py
class Block(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.slug is None:
            self.slug = get_unique_slug(self, 'title', 'slug')
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("bulkapp:one_view", kwargs={"slug_id": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```py
def edit_block_view(request, slug_id):
    single_block_query = get_object_or_404(Block, slug=slug_id)
    update_form_query = BlockForm(request.POST or None, instance=single_block_query)
    if update_form_query.is_valid():
        update_form_query.save()
        return redirect('bulkapp:one_view', slug_id=slug_id)
    return render(request, 'bulkapp/update.html', {'update_form': update_form_query})
```

```html
<form class="form-container" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{update_form.as_p}}
  <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Edit:

forms.py

```py
class BlockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Block
        fields = [
            "title",
            "slug",
            "content",
        ]
```

The redirect fires as expected, but no changes are saved, and no error messages are written to the console. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if self.slug is None:` blocks the save method if slug is already defined

Comment: @PRMoureu, I tried your suggestion, and no luck. I still get the same result, even after removing the def save() entirely.

Comment: so can you post the `BlockForm` code  please ?

Comment: @PRMoureu, Added the code you requested.

Comment: cannot say what goes wrong here, can you try to move 4 spaces back `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` in the method `save`  and add some log/print to make sure how it is triggered  ?*

Comment: @PRMoureu, looks like your suggestion was the real cause, and reason it didn't work was because i had added an `action="."` to my html form while testing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ;-) Glad it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the indentation of the `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` in my save() function which didn't execute if it the slug was not null.